# X axis label as Category not showing correctly: Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As I am trying to create a dynamic streaming Chart in Highcharts API, I came up with a strange problem.

1st thing to keep in mind is that I need to show the X-axis data as `category` that's why I have turned the `date` to a string format for this example.

The problem arises is that the X-axis label is not showing correctly only one point in x-axis is visible and that is also changing its values rather than shifting.

Here is the JS Code that I have tried.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function() {
              var series = this.series[0],
                    chart = this;
                var count = 0;
                 var draw = setInterval(function() {

                    x  = countval(); 
                   //   var counter = j;
                   //   console.log("Count: ", counter);
                      y = next();
                   console.log("CountVal : ", x);
                   console.log("DataPoints: ", y);
                 /* if (counter == 1300) {
                        clearInterval(draw);
                        return;
                    }
           */
                    if (counter > 1000) {
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true, false);
                    } else {
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, false, false);
                    }
                }, 1000/130 );
             }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'ECG Graph Plot From MySQl Data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        tickInterval: 200,
     /*/   labels: {
      format: '{value:%H:%M:%S}',
      range: false,
    },/*/
      //  plotLines: generateDynamicPlotLines(),
       // crosshair: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
      /*/  headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'/*/
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
     plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
        }
    },
    series: [{
            animation: false,
            name: 'ECG Graph Plot From MySQl Data',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
            data: []
        },

    ]
});
```

For further understanding, you can check this fiddle that I have which shows my problem. you can see the problem with X-axis.

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/8jtz2fwy/

I set the `tickInterval` to 200 it does not plot any point. and if I put `tickPixelInterval`. the X-axis points just updating their no's rather than shifting.

Comment: Hi @Chempooro, `tickInterval: 200` with `category` axis type causes that only every 200th tick is generated. Shift animation is not supported in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting xAxis.type to 'datetime' in place of 'category'.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question above. I need the category on X-axis label, I know datetime would give me the desired result.